# Records where boolean true for each element of array - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, where-clause

Using rails 4.

I have a `Spot` model with 7 boolean attributes for each day of the week: `monday:boolean`, `tuesday:boolean`, `wednesday:boolean` etc.

Users should be able to select a date range, and have only the spots that are available on those days be returned.

Currently having trouble setting up the class method that finds the correct records.

So far, I am creating a range from the dates the user enters, which returns all days of the week in that range.

```
range_array = (start_date..end_date).to_a.map{ |date| date.strftime("%A").downcase }
=> ["wednesday", "thursday", "friday"]
```

And here's where I am getting stuck. I am trying to find all spots where the boolean field corresponding to the element in the array is true. So in the example above, I would like to form this query `Spot.where(wednesday: true, thursday: true, friday: true)`

Is doing something like this possible? Is there a better/different way? Maybe I am going about this wrong. Thanks for any help/suggestions.

**Update** (for Andrey)... `Spot.first` example instance:

```
=> #<Spot id: 18, address: "4640 east skyline", title: "iodjiojoidj", description: "<p>jijiojfojewoif</p>\r\n", 
created_at: "2016-03-30 04:54:07", 
updated_at: "2016-09-26 05:39:51", 
user_id: 13, timezone: nil, 
surge_pricing: nil, free: nil, monday: true, 
tuesday: true, wednesday: true, thursday: false, 
friday: false, saturday: false, sunday: false>
```

Comment: which database do you use?

Comment: sqlite3 @Andrey

Comment: Please, show us examplary instance of `Spot` model, like `Spot.first`

Comment: Updated, let me know if that works @Andrey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your `range_array`, you should be able to do your query as follows:

```
query = range_array.inject({}) do |h, e|
          h[e] = true
          h
        end

Spot.where(query)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. will try now @Jagdeep